# Improving read/write loops in Python

Tags: python

**Task:** I'm importing a .CSV files as a pandas dataframes. I'm writing one column of that dataframe to a .txt file. Importantly, each row of the column must only be written as one row in the text file, never more (hence stripping /n)!

I have a very large dataframe (2 million rows), and this loop is naturally very slow given the I/O overhead. Any suggestions for improvements?

```
for i in tqdm(data['column'].head(500)):
        f = open("Questions.txt","a", newline="\n",encoding='utf-8')
        f.write(i.strip("/n"))
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
```

Comment: You could try to open/close the file only once and call write only once per iteration.

Comment: Where comes the magic `500` from? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and this loop is naturally very slow given the I/O overhead

Most of the overhead is probably produced from the way you are opening/closing the file with each iteration. That could be easily fixed by moving these operations out of the loop:

```
f = open("Questions.txt","a", newline="\n",encoding='utf-8')
for i in tqdm(data['column'].head(500)):
        f.write(i.strip("/n"))
        f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Wouldn't `with open(...)` be more idiomatic?

Comment: @Phrancis I'm no python expert and can't really tell, but `with` code blocks are the most horrible and obfuscating things with any programming language I've seen.

Comment: @Phrancis Such `with` code blocks are a strong indication you should just split up these parts, and move it into a separate function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ think of `with` blocks in python as the equivalent of `using` blocks in C# or `try-with-resources` in java. They're a resource handling construct, nothing like the `With` blocks you may know from Basic dialects

Comment: @Vogel612 As mentioned, I just find such constructs just horrible and defeating the readability, well structuring and refactoring flexibility of code. It's quite similar in _any language_.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: you don't deal with the I/O and call into `numpy.savetext` instead. Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np

np.savetext("Questions.txt", data['column'].map(strip_newlines).head(500), newline="\n", encoding="utf-8")
```

This makes abundantly clear that you only care about a newline-stripped representation of the column 'column' in your dataframe. Note that I removed the progress bar from this. I expect this code to be blazingly fast in comparison to yours, because it does two things:

1. expensive I/O operations (open and close) are only done once
2. I/O is pushed from python into C++

Comment: That's probably what separates the theorists from the experts. Great answer!